# Why doesn't Apache redirect my IP address to the desired location on my server?

Tags: apache2

I made a simple page `/home/david/mainSite/index.html`. I then added a virtual host in Apache to redirect my IP address to this page.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 74.181.105.228
DocumentRoot /home/david/mainSite
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I go to `74.181.105.228`after restarting Apache, I get a page with this text instead of "index.html."

```
Welcome to mydomain.com!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Why does Apache redirect to the default page instead of "/home/david/mainSite/index.html"?

Here is how my "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default" file looks like.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have a this in your configuration? `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Comment: Yes, I have both `ServerName 74.181.105.228` and 
`NameVirtualHost *:80` in my apach2.conf file in that order.

Comment: In what file have you placed this `VirtualHost` block?  Do you see the requests in your `access_log`?  If you modify your logging configuration to include the `Host:` header (`%{Host}i`) and the canonical `ServerName` (`%v`), do you see what you expect?

Comment: I placed the VirtualHost block in a file called "mainSite.apache" within my "/etc/apache2/sites-available" folder, ran "a2ensite mainSite.apache", and then restarted Apache ("apachectl restart"). I don't think I see the requests in my access log. I'll try out the latter.

Comment: Do you know how I modify logging for access.log? I can't find the Apache directive to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that every time I access http://74.181.105.228 in my browser, the access log doesn't even log the most recent access. Weird... I did though figure out how to modify my access logs with the "CustumLog" directive.

Comment: You're probably modifying the wrong config file then ..

Comment: I'm using Apache 2, so I should modify "apache2.conf", right? The server does not restart if I mess up this file, so I think it's the right config file.

Comment: What does your `apache2/sites-available/default` file say?

Comment: Here's what the default file looks like: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/Docudocker/default-sitesAvailable.txt

Comment: try commenting out ServerName

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer! It was tricky.

In "apache2.conf", I originally had `ServerName 74.181.105.228`, which makes accessing 74.181.105.228 via a browser load the default page for my server.

Changing this value in "apache2.conf" to `ServerName mydomain.com` solves the problem since Apache no longer directs 74.181.105.228 to the default page of my server. In turn, I can direct 74.181.105.228 to load a page from a certain directory in my file system.

My virtual host block still remains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 74.181.105.228
DocumentRoot /home/david/mainSite
</VirtualHost
```

Comment: This answer helped me a bunch!  I'd like to point out that the same problem happens if the server automatically assigns your IP address as your ServerName (if the server is doing this, you should see a message like "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.222 for ServerName" or somesuch in your /var/log/httpd/error_log).